# Calling onComplete on an Observable after the first element or empty is emitted

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have an Observable called `myObservable`, and my goal is to call `onComplete`, for the very first element that is emitted, **OR** when empty is emitted.

So I'm doing this:

```
myObservable.firstElement().ignoreElement().subscribe { 
  // OnComplete is called. 
}
```

So I'm converting it to a Maybe using `firstElement()` then, converting that Maybe to a Completable using `ignoreElement()`. I want `onComplete` to be called either when Maybe calls `onSuccess` or `onComplete`.

Is this the right way?

Comment: make a test and see.

Comment: According to my test, yes my theory is correct. But I just wanted to make sure since the documentation is bit lacking.